# Using sql server 2008 and TDE is it possible to create a database backup that is not encrypted?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, tde

Is it possible to take a database that is using TDE and create a backup file that is not encrypted?

I know that I could create a backup, import into another database (using the key and certificate), turn off TDE and create a backup.

I'm wondering if there is a more straight forward approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope.  that would defeat the purpose of TDE.  if backup was unencrypted then anyone could get an easy copy of the database.